# Node.js Gulp src/dest 4.0 behaviour vs Gulp 3.6

Tags: node.js, gulp

Quick Summary of my question:

Does Gulp 3.6.0 dest() handle glob-base the same way as 4.0.0?

```
function other() {
    return src([
        path.join("src/**/*"),
        path.join("!src/**/*.{html,css,js,scss}")
    ])
    .pipe(fileFilter)
    .pipe(dest(dist));
}
```

Running Gulp 3.6.0 with the code above produced this result:

[image]

Note that the folders and files in question added to the dist folder by this code were:

```
-app
-assets
-config
favicon.ico
```

Now running the same code in 4.0.0 produces this:

[image]

I know that the glob-base is added on by default to the destination when it's piped through, however is this behaviour different to how gulp handled mirroring source to dest file directory structure in 3.6.0? The example would suggest otherwise.

If anyone could provide me with a solution for producing the same folder structure as supplied in my 3.6.0 result that would be great. I've tried gulp-flatten and gulp-rename but nothing is producing the desired result of nicely removing only the glob-base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm still not sure what the significance of upgrading to Gulp 4.0 actually was with relation to how glob-parent/glob-base is handled however I managed to get what I needed using the base option.

This option effectively nullified the additional **src** hard-coded path reference before /**/ in the path.

```
function other() {

var fileFilter = plugins.filter(function(file) {
    return file.stat.isFile();
});

var appFilter = plugins.filter(function(file) {
    return file.path.indexOf("\\src\\app\\") === -1;
});

return src(path.join(conf.paths.src, "/**/*"), { base: conf.paths.src })
    .pipe(appFilter)
    .pipe(fileFilter)
    .pipe(dest(conf.paths.dist));
}
```